# slice query using hector on cassandra composite column

Tags: cassandra, slice

need some help on filtering based on Composite column.

I am unable to get filtering on 2nd part of composite column for some reason -

```
create column family xxx with comparator= 'CompositeType(TimeUUIDType, UTF8Type, UTF8Type)' and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
```

Data in one row -

primaryKey -    uuid1:A:123 | uuid2:A:123 | uuid3:B:234| uuid4:C:555

```
Composite startComposite = new Composite();
startcomposite.addComponent(0,uuidStart,EQUAL)
Composite endComposite = new Composite();
endComposite.addComponent(0,uuidEnd,EQUAL)
```

Above gives correct result based on uuidStart and uuidEnd values

e.g. uuid1:A:123 | uuid2:A:123 | uuid3:B:234

now if i want only columns with 2nd part as 'A' -

```
Composite startComposite = new Composite();
startcomposite.addComponent(0,uuidStart,EQUAL)
startcomposite.addComponent(1,"A",EQUAL)
Composite endComposite = new Composite();
endComposite.addComponent(0,uuidEnd,EQUAL)
endComposite.addComponent(1,"A",EQUAL) OR  endComposite.addComponent(1,"A",GREATER_THAN_EQUAL)
```

it gives me - uuid1:A:123 | uuid2:A:123 | uuid3:B:234

i was expecting -  uuid1:A:123 | uuid2:A:123

Any inputs whats wrong here ....

Code i am using -

```
    SliceQuery<String, Composite, String> sliceQuery = HFactory
            .createSliceQuery(keyspace, ss, cs, ss);
    sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("xxx");
    sliceQuery.setKey(primaryKey);


ColumnSliceIterator<String, Composite, String> csIterator = new ColumnSliceIterator<String, Composite, String>(sliceQuery, startcomposite, endComposite, false);

    while (csIterator.hasNext()) {
        HColumn<Composite, String> next = csIterator.next();
        System.out.println(next.getName());
        System.out.println(next.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to have same value for all parts of composite to slice. so changed the order.

Answer (score 0):

No surprise why it is returning the result since you have used `GREATER_THAN_EQUAL`.

Comment: As i mentioned above, same result with -      endComposite.addComponent(1,"A",EQUAL)                                    i.e. - uuid1:A:123 | uuid2:A:123 | uuid3:B:234